# How send data node.js to ejs file, and get data with angular.js

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, ejs

I have a problem with this.

I don't understand the method to send data to a ejs file with node.js and get theses data with Angular.js

Node.js part

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM movie', function(err, rows, fields) { 
    res.render('pages/index', {
        results: JSON.stringify(rows)
    });
  })
});
```

Angular part

```
$http.get('/').then(function(data) {
  $scope.movies = data;
  console.log(data);
});
```

index.ejs part

```
<main ng-controller="mainController">

  {{ movies }}

</main>
```

Comment: What exactly you are not understanding?

Comment: Are you getting results in index.ejs ??

Comment: I have no result in index.ejs, in console that me return the entire structure of index.ejs not just the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS is executed server side, `ejs` template is rendered server side.

Angular is executed client side (browser side) after the page has been loaded.

What you are currently doing is :

- Access url `/`in your browser
- which activates the '/' route in NodeJS
- which renders the template `index.ejs`
- This html page generated from the template is sent back to your browser and displayed
- Your browser find in this html page a javascript part, which runs an asynchronous request on '/'
- This request goes back to NodeJs again, re-render ejs template, and give you an html page in response. That's what your are seeing in the console.

You need :

- Either have a static page with javascript requesting on a NodeJS route, that answers **only json**. This JSON will be used javascript side to add content to the page.
- Or either generate, server-side, with the help of ejs template engine, a full page with all informations needed. (and then you don't need an asynchronous request in Javascript to get the content)

Comment: You're welcome. Could you accept the answer if it answered your question ?